# How to use contextmanagers for instance variables

Tags: python, destructor, with-statement

How would I use a Contextmanager for instance variables? E.g.
Let's assume I've got some `Connection` class, that must be closed on destruction. If I were to implement it as a ContextManager I could do.

```
with Connection() as c:
    c.write('FOO')
    c.ask('BAR?')
```

and it would get automatically closed on destruction. But what if I wanted to use it in a `__init__` of another class, e.g. like the following example?

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = Connection()  # Must be closed on destruction.
```

I dont want it to be closed on exit of the constructor, it should die when the object get's destroyed. I could use `__del__` but this has it's downsides. Being used to RAII in C++ it baffles me.

So what is the best way to do it in this case?

Comment: Object destruction time is never the right time for anything, especially not for resource management. Forget that there's there's such a thing as garbage collection and assume all objects live indefinitely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should invoke `self.connection.close` in your `Device.close()` method, and then arrange for that to be invoked properly in your program, perhaps with a context manager.

`__del__` is never worth it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def connection():
    conn = Conn()
    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close()

class Conn(object):
    def close(self):
        print('Closing')

class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = Conn()

with connection() as conn:
    d = Device(conn)
```